# Amazon Redshift string to list remove multiple single qoutes

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

Hi I am trying to remove single qoutes from a string and wanted to change it in list,
I have the input like `'''12345'',''12345'',12345'''` I want output like `('12345','12345,'12345')` I have tried `trim('''12345'',''12345'',12345''', '''')` But its giving me `56963','57296','57394` I want list not array so string_to_array is not useful for me. Actually I need it in exact format like `('12345','12345,'12345')` list in WHERE clause in DELETE statement, also its an requirement so please help me to get this output. Thanks in advance

Comment: hi, interesting, not sure, perhaps the [`REPLACE`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_REPLACE.html) function might be of use

Comment: How to use it in WHERE clause?

Comment: I'm trying `WHERE code in (replace('''12345'',''12345'',12345''', '''', ''))` but its not working

Answer (score 0):

I would approach this with few steps.

First remove all single quotes from string:

```
REPLACE(column, "'", "")
```

Second add single quotes around comma:

```
REPLACE(column, ",", "','")
```

Third concatenate start and end of string with single quotes and you end up with something like this:

```
"('"||REPLACE(REPLACE(column, "'", ""), ",", "','")||"')"
```

This can be solved by using REGEX as well and some other methods but this is what first came in mind. With this you are cleaning unnecessary quotes and structuring in a way that is useful for you.

Hope it works since I didn't test :)